# Eclipse quick fix not working properly

Tags: java, eclipse

I am very new to Eclipse, java programming and well all "programming" in general and I have recently been learning how to use Eclipse. I've been using it for about a week now and it has been going decent so far. Apart from some errors,(mostly on my part) that has been fixable by restarting the program itself.

However when I started using it today I could no longer see the suggestions made from the Quick Fix command, for example if I type findVi and then press CTRL+1, it shows "No suggestions available" instead of "findViewById()" or something similar.

I know it's the correct binding, I even reset the keys to default to be sure. It still finds the ID if i type it manually but I would like to able to finish words faster that way.

If you guys got any suggestions that can help me out, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a series of build errors? Check your markers in the JavaEE perspective of the Errors in the Java perspective. Eclipse can't make a suggestion if the build path isn't working (for instance if the JRE isn't bound).

Oh, and crtl-space is rather effective instead of quick-fixing. You're firing the auto-complete function.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I'm not sure what errors you are talking about but in the JavaEE perspective the errors are the same as in the Java perspective. Also CTRL+SPACE works! I still have no idea about what happened to CTRL+1 but i will be using CTRL+SPACE from now on, thanks again!

Comment: CTRL+1 will give you solutions to broken code (bad spelling/missing type etc...) ctrl-space is auto-complete which will let you "type-ahead" and inspect. They are both awesome features and Eclipse is a very solid IDE. They are both equally useful. Read up on the terms and good luck.

Comment: i will suggest you to launch a new eclipse application. That happens once with me too and worked.

Comment: I would suggest you move on to a better IDE ;)

Answer (score 1):

**-** First of all if you are **new with Java**, and want to practice Java, you should **NEVER USE ANY IDE**, that way you learn the proper syntax, and it helps your error finding skills.

**-** But as you wrote `"findViewById()"` it seems that you are doing Android, Now this happens sometimes that **Eclipse behaves weirdly with Android**. Thats the reason when you make any changes into your Eclipse GUI while working with Android, its always better to see if those changes have taken effect.

**-** This problem usually goes off after closing and re-opening the Eclipse once or twice.

**-** Ok try this....

Type `findVie` then press `Ctrl + Space-Bar` See if the suggestion pops up...

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply. Is there any specific guide or series of tutorials you would recommend for a beginner to Java or programming in general? Also pressing CTRL + Space-Bar does work well :)

Comment: Well if you want Java Guide, then begin with Head First Java, then after religiously studying it, move on to SCJP Programmer's Guide by same author Kathy Sierra and Bert Bates, then after that study the  Thinking in Java by Bruce Eckel

Comment: +1 for "This problem usually goes off after closing and re-opening the Eclipse once or twice."

Comment: I almost completely disagree with the **"never use any ide"** while learning. The IDE provides rapid feedback of what you are doing right and wrong syntax wise. Why you would not want the feedback quicker for learning is beyond me. I suppose training you to read compiler errors?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Content Assist preferences from *Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist*... perhaps something got messed up.

Comment: I've reset everything in there and also enabled all proposals and it does propose stuff just not the words.